# Terraform dynamic depends_on

Tags: terraform, dependencies

I have a generic module (modules/escalation_policy) with a resource block as follows defined in it:

```
resource "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "escalation_policy" {
    name = var.name
    …more stuff
}
```

Inside another file, I have this generic module being called multiple times as follows:

```
module "escalation_policy_1" {
    source = "./modules/escalation_policy"
    name = "Escalation Policy 1"
}

module "escalation_policy_2" {
    source = "./modules/escalation_policy"
    name = "Escalation Policy 2"
}
```

In a completely separate generic module, I have a data block defined which references the escalation_policy based on an input variable (name).

```
data "pagerduty_escalation_policy" "escalation_policy" {
    name = var.escalation_policy_name
}
```

How can I create a dependency (depends_on) inside of my data block which requires the escalation_policy_x module to be created first? I'm not aware of a way to do this with a dynamic name and I'm receiving the following error without it in place:

`Unable to locate any escalation policy with the name: Escalation Policy 1`

Comment: You are correct. That's not possible.You have to ensure the existence of escalation_policy_x before you invoke TF script with ` var.escalation_policy_name`. It has nothing to do with TF.

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation!